# Issue between Office 2010 and Visual Studio 2008 in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Not exactly a programming question in the technical sense, but it's impacting my development nonetheless and I'm hoping someone here might have encountered and solved this issue before.

I recently got adventurous and installed Office 2010 beta onto my PC here, and I've noticed that Visual Studio has begun to hang whenever I'm editing an ASPX file, sometimes right away, sometimes after a few minutes.  In my research I came across this post:

http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/5/12/visual-studio-2008-locks-or-freezes-in-aspx.html

It seems to imply that there's a dependency between Office and Visual Studio.  Is anyone here successfully running Office 2010 64-bit with Visual Studio 2008?  I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, also.

Josh

**Edit:** I have confirmed that the Setup.exe file referenced in that post is in fact being run by VS.  It is indeed a vestige of the Office 2007 suite.  I moved the directory it was in, and (of course) the process isn't spawned, but VS hangs on "loading cache" on this project.  I think I'm getting closer though.

Comment: I noticed an editor changed the tags to read `visual-studio-2010`. Note this is VS2008 and Office 2010.  This is not an issue with VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, doing a repair install of the Office-based Visual Web Developer component wouldn't work — the setup application kept crashing.  I ended up solving this problem by doing a complete reinstall of Visual Studio.  For some reason, doing a simple repair wasn't possible — the VS setup kept crashing, too.

I did a manual remove using [an uninstall tool designed for the VS2008 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/joy/archive/2009/10/16/microsoft-visual-studio-2008-rc-rtm-uninstall-tool.aspx).  It did a complete install of all VS components, after which point I reinstalled VS2008, which in turn reinstalled the Office-based visual web developer component.

It was a long and painful process, but it worked.  It didn't seem to be a direct incompatibility between Office 2010 and VS2008, as we have another PC here with the same combination that wasn't having the problems.  I believe it had to do with the fact that my PC originally had Office 2007, which I had to uninstall before installing Office 2010.  The other PC that wasn't having this problem never had Office 2007.  I can only assume that the uninstall process for Office 2007 either removed those Visual Web Developer components or removed dependencies that were originally put in there by the VS2008 setup program.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2009/07/19/office-2010-gotcha-2-visual-studio-2008-locks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

office 2010 runs on wpf and its major portion is build on dotnet framework. And there is always connectivity between office and vs coz vs can make office apps also. If you use office 2010 as your default for aspx page editor and vs is also opened with the same project. it will sometimes hang due to lack of resources and also vs 2008 was made for 32bit os, so if ur running it on 64bit os with office 2010 64bit it can sometimes cause problem of resouce management. Already wpf uses hell lot of resouces and then 32bit vs 2008' connection to it will use more resouces.

So what i suggest is try to use 32bit 7, 32bit office 2010 ans vs 2008.

Regards,
Apurva

Comment: Office isn't my editor -- all editing takes place in VS.  As for downgrading to 32-bit, not a chance.  My PC's never run faster or better, and I've never actually been able to address all the memory it has.  This is truly the *only* problem I've experienced.